# get the background image dimension

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background

I want to make this design responsive for that I will need the background image dimension (width, height) using javascript or JQuery. Any Ideas ?

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="result" class="result">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="slot-container">
            <div id="slot1" class="slot"></div>
            <div id="slot2" class="slot"></div>
            <div id="slot3" class="slot"></div>
        <div><button id="control" class="btn">START</button></div>
        <div id="try" class="result try">TRY 0</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/h0fbha33/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).on("load", function () {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = $('.slot').css('background-image').replace(/.*\s?url\([\'\"]?/, '').replace(/[\'\"]?\).*/, '');
    alert( img.width + ' and ' + img.height);
});
```

Here is the fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/beroza/a01y1me4/

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it is returning 0 0

Comment: Okay, let me make it compatible in all browsers.

Comment: This solution is not working, is there other way or plugins to complete this task ?

Comment: not working in chrome when do I have to execute the script ? on load or ready ?

Comment: Let me check it first by executing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
var img = new Image;
img.src = $('body').css('background-image').replace(/url\(|\)$/ig, "");
var bgImgWidth = img.width;
var bgImgHeight = img.height;
```

Comment: I want the dimension of .slot background image without background-image property